# Apply Solr filter only if token is longer than X chars

Tags: solr

I'm a Solr begginer thrown in at deep end :)
I'm dealing with a custom field type with filters defined as below:

```
<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```

after that, there's a Stem Filter defined.

I'd like to apply stemming only if the token is longer than X chars, is this possible in Solr?

I know that there's a `<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="7"/>` available, but it will just cut off words not matching it's criteria instead of just letting them bypass the stemming.

Any ideas on how to solve it?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Stemmers usually ignore words marked as **keyword**.

So, you want to add a [KeywordMarkerFilterFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/KeywordMarkerFilterFactory.html) into your chain before the stemmer.

To mark the words of at least X chars, you can use the parameter **pattern**, which takes Java regular expression. So, even something as basic as "**.{13,}**" (match any 13 characters or longer) should work.